# How do I display SQL errors from Spring and MyBatis?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I have the following code that I ran in the debugger with `--debug` but it won't print out any SQL errors. It fails silently with an exception and returns from the servlet request.

```
    System.out.println("sourceMapper = " + sourceMapper);
    Source source = sourceMapper.findByHost(host);
    System.out.println("source = " + source);
```

This is the output

```
2018-05-11 13:47:58.080  INFO 29392 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.shorturl.apis.ShortUrlApiController  : Method name: doUrlRequest() user agent is = curl/7.59.0
sourceMapper = org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy@30a1e904
2018-05-11 13:47:58.359  INFO 29392 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2018-05-11 13:47:58.489  INFO 29392 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2018-05-11 13:47:58.541 DEBUG 29392 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@645ec595
```

How do I print the SQL errors that it is encountering? Or find out why it's failing and what the exception is?

MyBatis 3.4.5, MyBatis Spring 1.3.1, MyBatis Spring Boot Autoconfigure 1.3.1, MyBatis Spring Boot Starter 1.3.1, Spring Boot 1.5.6

Comment: Why do you think there is any error? Those error code-related messages just inform you that error code definitions has been loaded on startup.

Comment: Because it didn't print "source = ..." and when I step over the line in the debugger it jumps to the random class `InvocableHandlerMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `try/catch` around your code and log a caught exception:

```
try {
    System.out.println("sourceMapper = " + sourceMapper);
    Source source = sourceMapper.findByHost(host);
    System.out.println("source = " + source);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // log using slf4j's Logger
    logger.error("An exception caught", e);
    // or print it to standard output
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There should be a `Logger` instance somewhere (probably in the same class):

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```